# Why does management.server.port not work?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application using actuator and in the `application.properties` I have defined:

```
server.port=9090
management.server.port=10080
```

AFAIK the `management.server.port` is to expose the actuator endpoint on another port different from the application's exposed port. I would expect that both should work:

```
http://localhost:9090/abc
http://localhost:10080/actuator
```

but only http://localhost:9090/actuator works and ONLY if `management.server.port` is out commented.

`http://localhost:10080/actuator` results in an empty page in the browser.
`http://localhost:9090/actuator` results in a white label error page with *There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).* in the browser.

How can I achieve setting both, server.port and management.server.port, both returning content?

Comment: what do you get in console when you request http://localhost:10080/actuator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

port '10080' is blocked by your browser for security reasons (*prevent NAT slipstreaming vulnerability*), use another one like '9091'

Answer (score 0):

try the default health endpoint: `http://localhost:10080/actuator/health`

Comment: The reference documentation disagrees with you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html

Comment: That's what I already did.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way to configure a new port. It works, but you're likely checking only via HTTP, and there it is not working due to what *@Dirk Deyne* mentioned.

But you can use the *10080* port for the actuator only you must access it via *JMX*. Test it with e.g. *JConsole* and you'll see that it is working. That is why you don't get any error messages.